# Passing a function as an parameter in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to create a function (last) that takes an function ( f ) and a List as an parameter. The list is passed to the function (odd?) and if the last element in the list is odd it returns true(#t) else it returns false (#f) .But the following code is not working , what is the correct way to declare the function as an parameter .

```
(define (last f L)
(if (null? L) '() ( last f (cdr L)) ))
```

> (last  odd? '( 0 5 3 8 6 7))

Comment: You don’t need to “declare the function as a parameter”; your issue is entirely unrelated. You have an extra set of parens around the inner expression, so the call should just be this: `(last odd? '(0 5 3 8 6 7))`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my question based on your comment .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here'a how you can write a solution using just built-in functions, notice the correct syntax for passing a procedure as a parameter, and also be aware that it's a bad idea to name your function as `last`, it clashes with an existing procedure, the very same that you should use to solve the problem!

```
(define (my-last f L)
  (f (last L)))
```

If you definitely have to write the function from scratch, then make sure that you understand what base cases are needed:

```
(define (my-last f L)
  (cond ((null? L) #f)
        ((null? (cdr L)) (f (car L)))
        (else (my-last f (cdr L)))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(my-last odd? '(0 5 3 8 6 7))
=> #t
```

Comment: Is there an way to write the solution without using `last` function ?

`(define (my-last f L)
    (if (null? L) '() ( my-last  f (cdr L)) ))`

Comment: @SivabalanBalasubramanian sure, by writing your own `last` function, but you shouldn't - always prefer to use built-in, existing functions: don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score -1):

For how you wrote the function, you have an extra parentheses set in the call. It should just be `(last odd? '(0 5 3 8 6 7))` as someone suggested you in the comments.